# How to pass a "don't care" function as callback while testing with Mocha and Sinon?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, callback, mocha.js, sinon

Here is my code:

```
var assert = require('assert')
var sinon = require('sinon')

// This is the business logic we want to test.
//
// Adds two numbers and returns the result. Also calls the callback with
// the result as argument when callback is defined.
function add(a, b, callback) {
  var result = a + b

  if (typeof callback !== 'undefined') {
    callback(result)
  }

  return result
}


describe('Tests', function () {
  it('test callback is called', function () {
    var callback = sinon.fake()
    add(1, 2, callback)
    assert(callback.calledWith(3))
  })

  it('test return value when callback absent', function () {
    var result = add(1, 2)
    assert(result, 3)
  })

  it('test return value when callback present', function () {
    var result = add(1, 2, sinon.fake())
    assert(result, 3)
  })
})
```

Here is the output:

```
$ node_modules/.bin/mocha foo.js 


  Tests
    ✓ test callback is called
    ✓ test return value when callback absent
    ✓ test return value when callback present


  3 passing (7ms)
```

I am concerned about the third test with description `'test return value when callback present'`. We don't care about the callback we pass to `add()` in the third test. I could have as well passed an anonymous function such as `function () {}` instead of `sinon.fake()`.  I see that I can also pass `sinon.stub()` or `sinon.mock()` instead of `sinon.fake()`.

With so many different choices, I am confused what is the appropriate argument to pass as a callback function when we do not care about the function at all? Since all four options: `function () {}`, `sinon.fake()`, `sinon.stub()`, and `sinon.mock()` seem to work fine, here is my question:

1. Does the `sinon` project or unit testing concepts demand that we use one option over another for this case, or are all four options equally technically correct?
2. Do we have to be aware of any pitfalls associated with one or more of these options?

Comment: Don't you still want to assert whether the callback was invoked or not?

Comment: @Matthew I have already tested that in the first test case. The third test case is about testing that the return value is fine regardless of what callback is passed.

Comment: Since you haven't given your fake in the third test case any behavior nor wrapped any functions with it or tested any calls to it, etc. it's pretty much the same as using a noop anonymous function `() => {}`. Since you don't care about the callback in that test case there's nothing wrong with the way you've written it that I can see.